# How to stop font size reduction in typesetting fractions and sub- and superscripts

Tags: formatting

When typesetting equations in *Mathematica* text cell if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> the numerator and denominator font is smaller than the base font. Similarly for sub- and superscripts. How do I tell *Mathematica* notebook to stop changing font size when going into fraction and subscript or superscript mode?

Comment: You may want to look at ScriptSizeMultipliers function, or ScriptMinSize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is controlled by the option `AllowScriptLevelChange`. If it is set to False, the font will not be smaller in the fractions.

There are several ways to do this.

A.  This will only keep the size of the fractions. The easiest is probably the switch off the script level changes that are taking place by selecting the cell bracket and setting

```
AllowScriptLevelChange -> False
```

in the options inspector. This is done as follows:

1. Open Menu/Format/OptionInspector.
2. Select the cell in question. It might be good to not only select the right bracket, but also the formula itself.
3. In the Option Inspector dialog the field "Show Option Values" should show "Selected". In the lookup text field type `AllowScriptLevelChange`.
4. In the bottom right window uncheck the checkbox at the option AllowScriptLevelChange.

Done.

B. This will control both the size of the fractions and of the exponents. You may adjust `ScriptSizeMultipliers` directly in the CellBox:

1. After you have typed the formula select the cell bracket and press Sift+Ctrl+E (Cmnd+Shift+E in Mac).  The cell structure will open.
2. Add

   `ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {1.0}`

as the option for the function Cell and again press Sift+Ctrl+E (Cmnd+Shift+E in Mac). This will close the CellBox and return you to the normal view. In this case not only fractions, but also exponents will show 100%.

C.

As the variant of B one can add the option `FractionBoxOptions->{AllowScriptLevelChange->False}` to the Cell function in the CellBox presentation making all actions described in B.

Have fun!

Comment: @ Michael E2 Yes, but this is what I have written, have not I?

Comment: @Michael E2 No, of course not. But it is not written in A that the approach will do everything. Therefore, I specifically noted it in the approach B. One can then try and decide, which one to use in what case.

Comment: Thank you it works but how do i do this programmatically.

Comment: Thank you it works but how do i do this programmatically globally for the frontend.

Comment: @Michael E2 You are right. I introduced some correrections to make it clearer.

Comment: @user13892 I guess you can. Note that I have never done this, and though theoretically, it must work, I am not sure. For this reason, if you want to try this, try it first for a single formula. To do this start with selecting the formula in question, and then open the OptionInspector and in its field "Show option value" select "Selection" and in "Lookup" type `ScriptSizeMultipliers`. Then play with the parameter in the curly bracket (that is, try to put it 1.0). If it works satisfactory make it for Global Preferences of the "Show option value" field.

Comment: @user13892 Some programmatic/global options: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {1.}]` changes it permanently (writes it to the file init.m); see also `$FrontEndSession`. `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {1.}]` sets it for a notebook. `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[expr, "Output", ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {1.}]]` creates a cell. `Style[expr, ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {1.}]` styles an expression or part of an expression; if you want to use the output algebraically, then `Style[expr, ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {1.}, StripOnInput -> True]` will be convenient.